# Integration shows RootSum and really long expressions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am doing this integration and when I use $C_\alpha(T)$ as just constant numbers(`Subscript[C, \[Alpha]][T_]= Piecewise[{{1.2, T < 100}, {8, T > 1000}, {5, 100 <= T <= 1000}}]`), I am able to plot the graph nicely. But once I use a straight line equation in that Piecewise function, integration shows weird answers. What am I doing wrong here?

````
Remove["Global`*"];
f[p_, T_] := 1/(Exp[p/T] + 1)
Needs["Rubi`"]

\[Theta] = (7*10^-11)^(1/2)
Subscript[M, 1] = 2*10^-3
Tf =100

Subscript[C, \[Alpha]][T_] = 
 Piecewise[{{1.2, T < 100}, {8, T > 1000}, {8 + (900/6.8)*(T - 1000), 
    100 <= T <= 1000}}]

\[CapitalGamma][p_, T_] = 
 Subscript[C, \[Alpha]][T]*10^-11 *  p* T^4 // PiecewiseExpand

\[CapitalDelta][p_] := (Subscript[M, 1]^2 /(2*p))

h[p_, T_] = (1/
      8) (\[CapitalGamma][p, T]* \[CapitalDelta][p]^2 * 
       Sin[2*\[Theta]]^2)/(\[CapitalDelta][
         p]^2 + (\[CapitalGamma][p, T]/2)^2) // FullSimplify // 
  PiecewiseExpand

fDW[p_, t_] = 
 f[p*t/Tf, t] Integrate[h[p*t/1000, t], t] // PiecewiseExpand

x[a_, b_] := a/b

xf = Table[{x[p, T], x[p, T]^2*fDW[p, T]}, {p, 1, 10^3}, {T, 100, 500,
     100}] // N

plot1 = ListLogLogPlot[xf, AxesLabel -> {x, Subscript[x\.b2f, DW]}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(1\)]\)=7keV,\[Theta]\.b2 = \
7x10⁻¹¹"]]






```
````

Comment: What "straight line equation" did you use that caused problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exact values until the `Table` for `xf` is calculated.

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[p_, T_] := 1/(Exp[p/T] + 1)
```

Use of `Rubi` is not necessary

```
(* Needs["Rubi`"] *)

θ = (7*10^-11)^(1/2);
Subscript[M, 1] = 2*10^-3;
Tf = 100;

Subscript[C, α][T_] = Piecewise[
  {{6/5, T < 100}, {8, T > 1000}, {8 + (2250/17)*(T - 1000), 
     100 <= T <= 1000}}];

Γ[p_, T_] = 
  Subscript[C, α][T]*10^-11*p*T^4 // PiecewiseExpand;

Δ[p_] := (Subscript[M, 1]^2/(2*p))

h[p_, T_] = (1/
       8) (Γ[p, T]*Δ[p]^2*
        Sin[2*θ]^2)/(Δ[
          p]^2 + (Γ[p, T]/2)^2) // FullSimplify // 
   PiecewiseExpand;

fDW[p_, t_] = f[p*t/Tf, t] Integrate[h[p*t/1000, t], t] // 
  PiecewiseExpand;

x[a_, b_] := a/b
```

**EDIT:** To eliminate complex artifacts (imaginary parts negligible compared to real part) use high precision and  `Chop[#, 10^-30]&`. Also note that the iterators in the `Table` are done in the opposite order to group by `T` values .

```
xf = Table[{x[p, T], x[p, T]^2*fDW[p, T]},
     {T, 100, 500, 100}, {p, 1, 10^3}] //
    N[#, 20] & // Chop[#, 10^-30] &;

plot1 = ListLogLogPlot[xf,
  Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, Subscript[x\.b2f, DW]}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(1\)]\)=7keV,\[Theta]\.b2 = 7x10⁻¹¹"],
  PlotLegends ->
   LineLegend[Range[100, 500, 100],
    LegendLabel -> "T"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But even when I am running this, the integration result still contains `RootSum` and I am getting complex values in the `Table` for `xf` where it is supposed to be just real numbers

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `RootSum` it is just a means of representing an exact number that cannot be represented by radicals. You can eliminate the complex artifacts by using `Chop` with the threshold set several orders of magnitude below the smallest real value. See edit.